# Inject runtime dependency into nix package

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

Adding a runtime dependency to a package through override buildInputs causes the package to rebuild. Is there a simple way to inject runtime dependencies into a package without recompiling?

So basically adding package/bin to PATH and package/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose of being purely functional, wouldn't it? (-> NO)

Comment: actually I think there is a way, looking at cc-wrapper, it swaps out binutils for example without having to rebuild gcc, so you could also use it to add a runtime dependency. `echo ${toString extraPackages} > $out/nix-support/propagated-native-build-inputs`

Comment: but I like that you cited me =P

Comment: So you mean to change the environment used when a Nix-installed app is *run*, not the one used when it is *built*, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to tweak the environment used when a Nix-installed app is *run*, not the one used when it is *built*, then a method I know of is as follows below. By using it, you essentially create a *wrapper script*, which overrides the "default command". So, something similar like creating e.g. a custom `~/bin/vim` script, which adds some options/env overrides to the default vim binary, which is called with a "hardcoded original path" inside the script.

One example of it in nixpkgs is how [vimutils.vimWithRC](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/963327aacb67322c8cc1ace863e7747823aa89e0/pkgs/misc/vim-plugins/vim-utils.nix#L281) overrides `vim` command with a custom script. For your own use, you could write more or less something like below:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

writeScriptBin "vim" ''
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  export PATH=package/bin:$PATH   # whatever you like; I've added what you asked for
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=package/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  ${vim}/bin/vim --my-options "$@"
'';
```

If you put it in `my-vim.nix`, you should be able to install it with:

```
$ nix-env -e vim   # REMOVE NORMAL VIM. I think this should be done first to avoid conflict
$ nix-env -i -f my-vim.nix
```

And hopefully it'll work and "override" the default vim for you.

***DISCLAIMER: I haven't actually tested it in this exact form, sorry. Don't have a Nix console handy at this moment, unfortunately.***